# VS solution configuration affects window resolution when creating window with SDL

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, sdl

My application starts with different resolutions depending on whether I build it in Debug or Release configuration. This behavior is unwanted and unexpected.

Window is created this way:

```
screen->window = SDL_CreateWindow(WINDOW_TITLE, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, screen->width, screen->height, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
```

screen-width and screen-height are defined in a header.

```
#define SCREEN_WIDTH 1024
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 800
```

When I run it with DEBUG configuration, it seems to run in the desktop display mode (1080p). In release, it runs as if the desktop was 1024x800.

[image: First]
**vs**
[image: Second]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the application had "Disable display scaling on high DPI settings" option enabled in application properties. When I disabled it, the issue went away.